# Difference between ndarray.transpose and numpy.transpose

Tags: python, numpy, transpose

What is the difference between `ndarray.transpose` and `numpy.transpose` ? and in which scenario, we have to which one ? is there a scenario where only one of the above will work ?

I have gone through the documentation and per my understanding `numpy.transpose` will return a view whenever possible. Whereas `ndarray.transpose` returns a view always.

It would be great if someone could give me some example where only one of the above is a good fit.

Comment: In general, the function form is useful if you do not know whether to expect a proper array or just an "array-like" such as a nested list.

Comment: Thanks you Paul. Do you mind showing a small code snippet that shows the difference (or) that shows one of the above could work and other is not.  Thank you again.

Comment: For example `A = [(x,x*x,-x) for x in range(5)]` is a list, not an array. Lists have no `transpose` method, so `A.transpose()` will raise an AttributeError. In constrast `np.transpose(A)` just works.

Comment: Thank you Paul. Understood. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The code for `np.transpose` is:

```
def transpose(a, axes=None):
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'transpose', axes)
```

which is, effectively:

```
np.asarray(a).transpose(axes)
```

that is, make a no-copy array and apply the method.

If `a` is already an array, the two approaches are essentially the same.  Either way `transpose` is a low cost operation, just changing `shape` and `strides` attributes. Use which ever makes your code clearest (that is, readable to a human).

Comment: Ok. So you are saying... both numpy.transpose and ndarray.transpose are essentially the same thing and they execute the same code and we can use them interchangeably everywhere ?  Thank you.

Comment: @Srik. They're interchangeable if you include the call to `asarray`